# How to achieve Depth field when rendering a 3D Gaussian Splatting scene?

Tags: camera, unreal

Is it possible to use depth of field when rendering 3D Gaussian Splatting in Unreal? I've tried playing with the camera settings but I can't achieve the blur effect.

[image]

Comment: any code to share ?

Answer (score 0):

In short yes, but without any code to preview I can only suggest you try watching this [tutorial on YT](https://youtu.be/xdDzChfFY_A) or others like it for more specific details.

But if you have already or another similar, then I would try something like:

1. Enable `Depth of Field` in `Post Process`
2. Adjust parameters related to `Focal Distance` and `Focal Region`
3. Modify your shader to account for any depth information by sampling your depth buffer to calculate your blur in relation to the distance of your focal point (e.g. the couch compared to the table)
4. Using the depth information you can then decide how much blur to apply to an indvidual pixel using the distance from your focal plane.

I pulled most of this off of the [Unreal Engine Documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/) and the above youtube video and am in no way an expert in Unreal engine. Best of luck and I hope I was of some help.